# How to set a variable separator

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, separator

I have a variable `$cameramodel` which contains term meta of a wordpress taxonomy:

```
<?php 
function cameramodel() {
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'camera');
$result = "";
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $result .= get_term_meta( $term_id, 'model', true );
}
return $result;
}

$cameramodel = cameramodel(); ?>
```

On the front end I would echo `$cameramodel`

```
<?php echo $cameramodel; ?>
```

There are instances where `$cameramodel` contains more than one value, but when I echo `$cameramodel`, They all appear on one line with no spaces. My question is, how do I make a separator between each value? I want each value to be on it's own line, and I would like to be able to separate them with the word "and".

For example, if the variable contains "one two three" it currently prints "onetwothree", but what I want is:

```
one and
two and
three
```

Hope I am being clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to edit the function slightly, I believe you will benefit from using an array and then joining it together into a string with the delimiter of your choice passed as an argument:

```
<?php 
    function cameramodel($delimiter) {
        # Get the terms.
        $terms = get_the_terms($post -> ID, "camera");

        # Create an array to store the results.
        $result = [];

        # Iterate over every term.
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            # Cache the term's id.
            $term_id = $term -> term_id;

            # Insert the term meta into the result array.
            $result[] = get_term_meta($term_id, "model", true);
        }

        # Return the elements of the array glued together as a string.
        return implode($delimiter, $result);
    }

    # Call the function using a demiliter of your choice.
    $cameramodel = cameramodel(" and<br>");
?>
```

Of course, you can embed the delimiter you want in the function as the first argument of `implode` instead of passing it as an argument.

[Here](https://3v4l.org/Pk6Cm) is an example using the same logic.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! I'm assuming if I want to use a variable as the delimiter I can do this? `$cameramodel = cameramodel($variable);`

Comment: One last thing, if I do this `$cameramodel = cameramodel($variable);` is there any way for me to style the $variable different than the strings? for example can I make the outputted strings bold and the delimiter not bold? Like this: **one** and
**two** and
**three**

Comment: Sure @AMerdaman. Change the line `$result[] = get_term_meta($term_id, 'model', true);` to `$result[] = "<b>" . get_term_meta($term_id, 'model', true) . "</b>";`

Comment: Right now I have it like this: `<h1 class=text><?php echo cameramodel(" and<br>"); ?><h1/>` and I have several styles on the h1 class. Is it still possible to style the delimiter differently? I tried `("<p> and<br><p/>")` but that also applied the `<p>` style to the next outputted line...

Comment: You can do whatever you want. E.g, make the delimiter: `" <span class = 'custom'>and</span><br>"` and give the `.custom` class whatever styles you want using CSS.